# I still use MS DOS style batch files (.bat) What should i be using these days, instead?

Tags: batch-file

Surely there better substitutes out there for this kind of simple scripting on windows?

I've tried googling but just get stuff about editing old batch files.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell, VBS, BAT - all completely acceptable because they all still work in Windows up to 8.1 and I don't see that changing any time soon. PowerShell, however, is probably the latest and greatest to use. Very powerful.

Comment: Heh, aside from modernizing the .BAT extension to .CMD, what works, works.